# Adding a value to a database colum with already set value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have three database tables where one of them works like a connector between the two other tables, a card table and a user table. The connector table has three columns: idUser, idCard and amount.

In my code I have a select button where you can choose to add 1-4 of the same card, this I want to be able to do by either by adding 4 right away or one at the time (I want the max value of the amount column to be 4).

As for now my code looks like this;

```
if (isset($_POST['addCard'])) {

    if (!isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])){
    print "fel!";

    }else {
        $idUser = $_SESSION['sess_id'];
        $idCard = $_POST['addCard'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO userDeck (idUser, idCard, amount) VALUES ('$idUser',    '$idCard', '$amount')";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
        }
}
```

This checks if a user is logged in, otherwise it just prints "wrong" (was just testing around), if logged in tho, this still just creates a new row in the table when I'm adding any number of cards.

I hope I've added what info you might need, really stuck on this so any help is appriciated, thanks!

Comment: `INSERT` queries always add a row if executed. You need to `UPDATE`. E.g. `UPDATE userDeck SET someCol = 'someVal' WHERE idUser = 1`

Comment: Make sure you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for **every** `$_POST` variable you pass to MySQL. This else will be an easy SQL-Injection possibility.

Answer (score 0):

switch (or add more logic) to include an `UPDATE` statement.

or change the database schema to not include the count, but instead just a list of cards per user - then you can deal with only INSERT when the user gets any new card, and DELETE when the user loses the card.

Answer (score 0):

The query might look something like this:

```
UPDATE userDeck 
SET amount = amount + $amount 
WHERE 
    idUser = $idUser AND 
    idCard = $idCard
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO userDeck (idUser, idCard, amount) 
VALUES ('$idUser', '$idCard', '$amount')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=amount+$amount
```

you need to have a composite unique or primary key on `(idUser, idCard)` fields.

**EDIT**: to enforce 4 card max with same query:

```
INSERT INTO userDeck (idUser, idCard, amount) 
VALUES ('$idUser', '$idCard', MIN(4, '$amount'))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=MIN(4, amount+$amount)
```

Comment: Tried this out and got it working, thanks! I can still add more than 4 cards tho, is there a way to set a maximum of 4 cards?

Comment: Worked just fine! Was just thinking, could you use a similar query to delete 1-4 cards and when the 4 is deleted remove the card from the list (empty the table row)?